Write test on reassemble logic
I've created a StatefulWidget and I have included some logic into reassemble to have a specific behavior when the developer hot reloads during development.
@override
void reassemble() {
  super.reassemble();
  // My logic.
}

I would like to write a test about it, how can I trigger the reassemble method?
tester.pump() doesn't seem to do the job as it only rebuilds the widget tree.

You can use tester.binding.reassembleApplication() for that:
testWidgets('Your test', (tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(const YourWidget());
  
  // Test your logic before `.reassemble()`.
  
  unawaited(tester.binding.reassembleApplication());
  await tester.pump();
  
  // Test your logic after `.reassemble()`.
});

